# What was the driving record of each rover on Mars in one sol, and when?

Tags: mars, rovers, mars-exploration-rover

Both Mars rovers [Opportunity and Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Exploration_Rover) had a top speed of [180 meters/hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Exploration_Rover#Drive_system) on flat hard ground, but their hazard avoidance software caused them to stop every 10 seconds for 20 seconds to observe and understand the terrain into which they had driven, so their average speed was [36 m/h.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Exploration_Rover#Drive_system)

[Curiosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)) could travel up to [90 m/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)#Specifications) but its average speed was [30 m/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)#Specifications), and its maximum terrain-traverse speed was estimated to be [200 m/sol.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)#Specifications)

What was the longest distance in one sol each rover drove, and when? 
Please provide references for the answers.

Comment: The answers are in "Robotic Exploration of the Solar System: Part 3" but I just returned that to the library last week!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I have an answer for only the MERs and MSL.  I have no idea how to find this information for Sojourner**.

**For Curiosity**: 144.04m on Sol 385 ([source](http://curiosityrover.com/tracking/drivelog.html)).  I processed that data in excel, but I don't know how to upload an excel file.  The data does include some sols with multiple traverses, but I accounted for that so the 144.04m figure is in fact the longest single day's drive.

**For the MERs**: I do not have a link, but I reached out to Dr. Raymond Arvidson, the deputy PI for the MERs.  He reached out to his computer systems manager, who gave me the following email answer:

> Hi Michael –
>       The maximum distance that each MER travelled in a single day was:   Spirit (MER-A) – 114.2m on sol 125, May 10, 2004 Opportunity (MER-B) –
>   228.1m on sol 410, March 20, 2005   Fun fact: the sol 410 drive was part of a sustained effort during which Opportunity drove an average
>   of 191.2m  on each of seven consecutive drive sols (406, 407, 408,
>   410, 412, 413, and 414).

So, kudos to both Ray Arvidson and Thomas Stein for the MER stuff.

Comment: You could save the data as a comma separated value (csv) file and then copy-paste it to your answer.

Comment: It is 717 lines long, though...

Comment: Upload to Google DOC and copy-paste link to answer

Comment: I see no need for sharing a spreadsheet. You have linked the data, and you have a numerical value for your answer. The processing can be reproduced by anyone.

Comment: Sols 1127, 1260, 1512, 1591 and 1730 have more than one drive, for those wanting to rank them by distance driven. None of those are long enough combined to challenge Sol 385.

Comment: This link https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/rover-status/opportunity/2005/all/  gives a distance of 220 meters on sol 410.

Answer (score 8):

New Martian records for the [Perseverance rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover)) !

On **sol 340 (Feb. 2, 2022)**  the rover drove **237.78 m**, but the following day the driving distance was even **240.73 m.** (according to the [Perseverance location map](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/mission/where-is-the-rover/)}

[image: Perseverance location]
Screenshot from the location map

Again, on **sol 351 (Feb. 14, 2022)** a record-breaking distance of **313.83 m.**

New record on **sol 753 (April 3, 2023)**, **328.66 m.**

Comment: Now that record is 367. Perseverance will probably beat it's own record several times in the coming weeks.