# When did Opportunity do its record-breaking traverse?

Tags: opportunity, mars-exploration-rover

Based on [an article by the Planetary Society](https://www.planetary.org/the-downlink/olympic-worthy-worlds-records), rover Opportunity used to hold the record for longest distance (214 meters) in a single sol. On what (Earth-)date did Opportunity do its longest drive?

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39102/6718) states that the longest distance MER traveled in a single day was 228 meters on sol 410. What does that correspond to in Earth-days? Based on [the MER website](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/rover-status/opportunity/2005/all/), I'm guessing it was a bit before March 31st 2005, but what was the exact date?

Comment: ```-1``` the Earth date is given in the linked answer...